# Best way to say I keep on doing something?

Tags: word-choice, tense, gerunds, present-continuous, style

What is better to say:

> - I am **continuing** to do something.
> - I am **carrying on** doing something.
> - I **keep doing** something.

How to say it better if, for example, I continue to make my mobile application better.

I'd like to put this text in release notes.

What's better in terms of general English and particular usage?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. That said, I think you mean: I'm continuing to improve my mobile app. I'm continuing to make my mobile app better. Either one.

Comment: In most contexts, a native speaker would probably say *I'm **still** [doing something],* but we'd need a much more precise context to say whether and which alternatives might be used instead.

Comment: You've got me right. I want to say "I'm continuing to improve my mobile app". To indicate a process which is still active and is planned to be active further.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably trying to say something like

> We appreciate your support and feedback ***as we continue to improve our app***.
>   We appreciate your support and feedback ***as we keep improving our app***.

which is a different situation than

> Q: How is your app coming along?
>   A: I am **continuing** to improve it *(every day)*.

**carry on** *(BrE)* is not quite right, since it often implies continuing from a stopping point which ou have not indicated happened.  It also has other meanings if you are not careful with context.